# How can I change a source of a video in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-component

I have used a react-video component in my reactjs web application and it's working with a default source link, but when I'm using my video as a source, nothing happens.

I have searched a lot, read the documentation about react-video component, but could not solve the problem.

```
import {Player} from 'video-react';  
<div className = 'video-container'>
<Player
playsInline
fluid={false}
src="https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer_hd.mp4"
width={600}
height={300}/>
</div>
```

I expect the new source to be working without any issues, but it never starts playing.

Comment: Maybe the issue is with your video? Any other video source (apart the default) is working?

Comment: Stupid question, but.. Where is located your video? Is hosted somewhere, or is it in the local machine?

Answer (score 1):

@Dato.Beriashvili, I have faced similar issues in default html video API, whenever i change src by anymeans video was not updated. so i have done below which fixed my issue.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const myVideo= innerDoc.querySelector('#videoPlayer');
  const mySource = innerDoc.querySelector('#source');
  if (mySource && myVideo) {
    mySource.setAttribute('src', videoUrl);
    myVideo.load();
  }
}, [videoUrl]);
```

whenever url changed, i'm manually loading it.